# What I' ve to write on the client's socket, if my server-side is a servlet?

Tags: java, android, sockets, servlets

I've created a client-servet connection

My server-side is a Web servlet that is on http://satisfied.altervista.org

My client-side is an Android APP.

My question could be stupid but when I create my client's Socket what ip should I put in?? 
Probably the Ip of the server on which my servlet is hosted? or Simply the link of my Servlet for example `Socket socket = new Socket("http://satisfied.altervista.org",7100);`???

Thanks guys and sorry for my stupid question but I'm new in this field.. :)

Comment: I guess it would be easier to try out the two variants instead of posting a question here. The documentation may also give valuable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your account weren't suspended at altervista.org, you'd put:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("satisfied.altervista.org",7100);
```

You're connecting to the IP address, but you're not using the HTTP protocol, so you only need the hostname.

Comment: This method could be good to create a Chat Application for you? Or should I make something different?

Comment: Are you asking if this method is good for a chat application? If so, then yes. But the connection has to be kept active which requires the phone to be on or awake (thus draining battery). If you want a chat application that can run in the background, I'd take a look at Google GCM or implementing your own WebSocket thing.

Answer (score 0):

As you *are* using the HTTP protocol, you should be using a URLConnection for this, or an external HTTP client. Not a Socket.